# Commission calculation based on sliding month (googlesheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have to pay a commission to Agents (affiliates) based on the following conditions:

- the commission starts on a monthly basis following a USER (linked to the Agent) first deposit/purchase on a website
- agents have a decreasing commission, ex: 1 month following first deposit of their USER = 30% of sales, 2d month period following 1st deposit of USER: 25% of sales, etc
- Commission are paid on a month basis calculation (ex: from 01/07/2020 till 31/07/2020)
- If a USER makes a first purchase on June 22d and if sales commission for 1st period is 30%, then agent is eligible to a 30% commission on sales from june 22d till July 22d, then 25% for sales from 23rd july till 23rd august, etc

I have designed a googlesheets (see below) that serves the purpose (using 12 columns to get the correct commission% for a specific user on a specific day!), but I am trying to find a more straight forward formula to get the applicable com. % based on the commission sliding table and the first deposit date of a specific user.

Can anyone help?

The google sheets showing my calc is here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I1gzZ670hJH8HwCGizzbvlQkg0dgAvgOSQTfOUL0VgU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.  (Updated to correct the row number of where the formula should go.)

If you insert a new column in your sheet, to the right of Column W, the Current Commision Month, and paste the following formula in the cell where the Current Commision Month header text should appear (Row 9 in your sample) of that column, it replicates the results in your Current Commision Month.

But it does not require columns I through V.  You can test that by deleting columns I through V - you can use Undo and Redo to go back and forth, if necessary.  Depending on how you use your "End" column - the logic wasn't clear to me - the info for that can also be gained in this one column.

```
={"Current
Commision
Month";"";ArrayFormula(
if(
  ($H11:H<>"") * ($A11:A>=date(year(H11:H),month(H11:H),day(H11:H))),
  ifs( $A11:A< date(year(H11:H),month(H11:H)+1,day(H11:H)),1,
       $A11:A< date(year(H11:H),month(H11:H)+2,day(H11:H)),2,
       $A11:A< date(year(H11:H),month(H11:H)+3,day(H11:H)),3,
       $A11:A< date(year(H11:H),month(H11:H)+4,day(H11:H)),4,
       $A11:A< date(year(H11:H),month(H11:H)+5,day(H11:H)),5,
       $A11:A< date(year(H11:H),month(H11:H)+6,day(H11:H)),6,
       $A11:A>=date(year(H11:H),month(H11:H)+7,day(H11:H)),9999),
  ""))}
```

The first IF test is to check that the FirstDeposit date is not blank, and that the sale date is greater than or equal to the FirstDeposit date.

The IFS tests go through and check whether the sale date is less than one of the months, and stops at the first value (commission month) that is greater than the sale date.  If never, it places a vlaue of 9999.
Note that the "9999" values are just to indicate the sale date is greater than the "End" date, and can be changed to blanks or whatever you want.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I've added a sample tab with the final result.  Let me know if this helps.  There may be several other enhancements possible for your sheet, in particular the use of `ARRAYFORMULAS` to fill values down many of your columns.

I haven't spent time on the actual commision calculations, in the final columns, but if you feel that still needs improvements, I can try to simplify there as well.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfFZ5.png

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help. I have put the editing rights on the sheet and will check your formula a bit later ...

Comment: I updated my above answer to correct what row to place the fomula in - Row 9 of your sample, not Row 1.  I also deleted 40,000+ empty rows, which may improve performance.  And if you take the approach with this formula, deleting columns I to V, with all of their formulas, that should also improve performance...